# How to remove .index.html from URL?

Tags: html, url

I would like to know is it possible to remove index.html, info.html from the URL? 
Also, what to add in

`<a href="here?">Start page</a>`

to make a start page like facebook.com. (Without facebook.com/index.html(php)?

Comment: Just use the domain name. e.g. `facebook.com` or a relative path `/`.

Comment: It's a server configuration.  When you land on a particular directory, you can set a list of default filenames to load.

Answer (score 0):

You use this:

```
<a href="/">Start page</a>
```

And you can set rewrite rules and stuff depending on server and access.
Wanna learn more, google for apache and rewrite rules and .htaccess if you are on an apache server. Else you are probably on a nginx server.